# How to get useState values inside getServerSideProps in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two functions one function takes input from user and other performs search for that supplied input data. I want to use `searchQuery` from `useState` inside `getServerSideProps` function.
Is there any way to do this?

```js
function SearchDemo() {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
  
    const ChangeHandler = event => {
      setSearchQuery(event.target.value)
    }
  
    const ButtonHandler = event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(`Data: ${searchQuery}`)
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={ButtonHandler}>
          <div>
            <label>Search:</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" value={searchQuery} onChange={ChangeHandler}/>
            <button>Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({query: {page}, searchQuery}){
    console.log(searchQuery)
    return {
        props: {
            data: data
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to push the url and reload the page, because it's serverside-rendered.

```
const router = useRouter()
const ButtonHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  router.push(`/thecurrentUrl?search=${searchQuery}`
  // if doesn't work then use window.location.href
  console.log(`Data: ${searchQuery}`)
}

export async function getServerSideProps({query: {page}, searchQuery}){
    console.log(query.search)
    return {
        props: {
            data: data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I searched about that as well and found this solution only. We have to push the same URL using router.push to invoke getServerSideProps again.

Comment: actually it's not necessary to call getServerSideProps when the page is already loaded, you can always use a normal fetch in your component. Hence, you allow both serverSide generated search results, as well as normal fetch results, if you know what i mean.